# Change Checkbox colorAccent at runtime programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox, colors, android-drawable, android-styles

I'm creating an ordinary Checkbox view:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image]

This light green (#A5D6A7) is due the accent color defined in the main style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green_light</item>
```

I already found that I can't change this style at runtime: *[How to set colorAccent in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595625/how-to-set-coloraccent-in-code)*

I want to change this color on a specific Checkbox, not globally over the app. Can I do it without creating a specific asset? Because the user will able to change this color at runtime.

Answer (score 20):

Below code will work smoothly without slowing down check and uncheck behavior of checkbox.because checkbox.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);  will behave unexpectedly on some devices

```
ColorStateList  colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                        new int[][]{
                                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked} , // checked
                        },
                        new int[]{
                                Color.parseColor("#cccccc"),
                                Color.parseColor("##cccccc"),
                        }
                );

 CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(checkBox,colorStateList)
```

Comment: I just encountered the "unexpected behavior" you mention, and this code saved the day! Thanks a bunch for sharing!

Answer (score 10):

Use [AppcompatCheckbox](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatCheckBox.html)

```
 AppCompatCheckBox acb = (AppCompatCheckBox)findViewById(R.id.acb);
 ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{

                     new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, //disabled
                     new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
                },
                new int[] {

                     Color.RED //disabled
                     ,Color.BLUE //enabled

                }
        );

  acb.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

Comment: With this solution, click is slower than usual, but works though!

Comment: try to extend AppCompatCheckBox, Add colorstate code; then see the performance @Lera

Comment: I'm not too in touch with Android anymore, can some of you confirm if this answer fix the problem pls?

Comment: I hope this solves the problem @MarceloFilho as i mentioned earlier you can also extend class from AppCompatCheckbox for performance

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
public void setCheckBoxColor(CheckBox checkBox, int checkedColor, int uncheckedColor) {
     int states[][] = {{android.R.attr.state_checked}, {}};
     int colors[] = {checkedColor, uncheckedColor};
     CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(checkBox, new 
         ColorStateList(states, colors));
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

For an API level greater than or equal to [Lollipop (21)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES#LOLLIPOP), try the below:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    checkBox.buttonTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_rose))
}
```

Comment: @PeterMortensen FYI it would probably be better to link to something with the numerical API level (here, 21) such as https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES#LOLLIPOP, rather than the Wikipedia article. (flag as NLN once you've seen this)